# Gradient symbols and letter f mtpro2

Tags: spacing, letterspacing, mtpro, gradient

So I notice that the spacing between `\nabla` and `f` 
in math mode when using mtpro2 is really wide (for me, at least). Here is the result of typing `\nabla f` with mtpro2.

[image: gradient of f]

I wonder if there is a way we can adjust the symbol `\nabla`
based on the next non-space letter, say:

1. If the next non-space letter is `f`, then execute `\kern -0.2 em f`,
2. else, stay at usual.

I have been looking around, but could not find a satisfying solution. Any help
is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask a question please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a Lua function called `nabla_f` that does most of the work, and it assigns this function to the `process_input_buffer` callback, making it operate on all inputs *before* TeX starts is usual processing.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times,mtpro2} % text and math fonts
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function nabla_f ( s )
   return ( s:gsub ( "\\nabla%s*f" , "\\nabla\\mkern-4mu f" ) )
end
\end{luacode}
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", nabla_f , "nablaf" )}

\begin{document}
$\nabla{}f$ $\nabla f$ $\nabla h$ $\nabla k$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you also want to change the amount of whitespace between `\partial` and `f`, while keeping the instruction to change the distance between `\nabla` and `f`, I suggest you replace

```
   return ( s:gsub ( "\\nabla%s*f" , "\\nabla\\mkern-4mu f" ) )
```

with

```
   s = s:gsub ( "\\nabla%s*f" ,  "\\nabla\\mkern-4mu f" ) 
   s = s:gsub ( "\\partial%s*f", "\\partial\\mkern-4mu f" )
   return s
```

Of course, you can (and should) change the new instance of `-4mu` to whatever the optimal adjustment amount may be.

Comment: so I guess this works for other things like `\partial f` by replacing `nabla` with `partial`? I am excited about this :)

Comment: @weirdo - Indeed, the code can be modified to allow further types of adjustments. I posted an addendum to show how this might be done for the case of `\partial` and `f`.

Comment: works like a charm for me :)